# HTTP/2: Does the server create a new stream to return to the client?

Tags: http2

I learned that when client or server have data they want to send to each other they will use stream. Data will be split into Frames and sent on the same `stream Identifiers`.
Client or server after receiving enough Fram containing data will reassemble into data.

I also know that the client will generate `Stream Identifiers` with odd numbers and the server will generate even numbers.

Question:
With HTTP there will be request and response. Does the Response use the same `Stream Identifiers`?

Example: Client sends request to Server with `stream Identifiers 1`. The server receives the request and processes it. When the server returns the response to the client, will it create a new `stream Identifiers is 2` or use the client's `stream Identifiers 1` to return data to the client?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP/2 stream is the flow of frames for both a request and its correspondent response, so you can think of `stream = request + response`.

When the server returns a response to a request, the response frames must use the same stream id as the request frames, because they belong to same stream.

Comment: Thanks,I have more questions.
So when will the server create the stream? just in case the server actively sends data to the client?

Comment: The concept of "stream" is a virtual concept, so there is nothing "physical" that gets "created". The client "creates" a stream by sending bytes (in the correct HTTP/2 format) on a TCP connection. The server parses those bytes, see that they belong to the HTTP/2 stream id 143, and replies by sending bytes (in the correct HTTP/2 format), encoding the same stream id it received, on the same TCP connection. The server may initiate a stream by sending bytes (in the correct HTTP/2 format) and those bytes must encode an even stream id.